# General Advice - Understanding the Construction of a Food Ordering Systems

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, laravel

First of all let me start by saying that this is not a how to do question.

I recently ordered pizza online from Pizza Hut and I noticed their awesome ordering system they have and this got me wondering on how these type of systems are constructed, I'm actually more curious about the app that receives the orders, is this just a typical email client they check for new emails(orders) or is it an app the refreshes every time a new item is enter in a database?

What are the parts of an ordering system?

Possible Parts...

- An HTML/PHP form that processes the order and money transactions.
- A database where the information sent by the user/client is stored.
- An app that fetches entries from a database, or just an email client.
  etc...

Any idea on how these systems are constructed?

I need to practice my PHP/SQL/Laravel skills and I think this system would be a good real world practice.

Thanks a lot

Comment: no one stooped u  to develop such a app...

Comment: The front-end may be integrated with a CRM + SCM & ERP solutions which handle the ordering and delivering process. You don't want to try code from scratches yours

Comment: Sometimes you can check how things are built directly... You may know a lot by checking the little letters/links on the page's footer like: "About us", "Careers", Design made by X", that will give you an insight to the authors or that technology/service itself. If you're really into Web Development, you can right click on the page and inspect the code, for example, with Firebug plugin you can check which requests are made to their server (network tab), which javascript plugins they use, or if it's all made by them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one table for orders, let’s call it “TempOrders”:

1. ID (autoincrement)
2. FoodItem (1=Pizza, 2=Fanta, 3=Ice Cream…)
3. Quantity
4. Table/Desk (for grouping orders, for online orders it could be virtual table)

Function: Create a bill (close the order, select type of payments, print the bill). When successful, move the records to another similar table, let’s call it “OrdersArchive”.

At the shift/day end, TempOrders should be empty and all records moved to OrdersArchive.

Sure, you also need table for FoodItems, preferably with types of items (Food, drink, cigarettes, etc) since you probably need it for reports.

My advice is to have an attribute for price in both FoodItems table and TempOrders / OrdersArchive because when price changes it would be much easier to deal with it (although it violates database normalization).

Also, you can use separate table for OrderHeader instead of Table/Desk attribute. Working that way, you can have clear Master-Detail structure (if you like it that way).

I don't believe e-mail is good idea for this kind of system, in today world everyone wants on-line application to get immediate response. What if you are out of stock with Coke or Coffee? You need to send that info back to customer immediately.

Comment: `I don't believe e-mail is good idea for this kind of system, in today world everyone wants on-line application to get immediate response.` So, would you say that the restaurant would have a unique interface where they see the orders which fetches orders from the “TempOrders” db every a few seconds? Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: Just pointed that e-mail is quite slow for this type of business. Some 10 years ago it was OK, but today we have an plethora of technologies which can do that much better with equal amount of code. See" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API

Comment: Got it, I'm actually familiar with those technologies I just have never seen these type of systems in real world and I was wondering if they still use email as the main interface to get the orders or an iPhone/iPad, Android or online app. Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

Comment: Just for reference, I found very good information here. https://ivi.fnwi.uva.nl/fcn/teaching/2007-dbp-ik/Studentprojectreport/group1.pdf

Comment: This reference is great, one can learn a lot from this paper.